# Replace text with Regex override

Tags: regex, overriding

I've recently discovered import.io, and interesting web crawler. Now this program allow me to change the crawled data with a "Manual regex override", but I can't figure out how to use it. I have a field which contains for example this string

```
Actors: Jhon, Mike
```

And I want to use this Manual regex override feautre to match for example the comma and turn it into a "|" or delete the string "Actors: " and keep only "Jhon, Mike"

Comment: use this regex `^\S+\s*` and then replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: Ok I've only one field to compile, and if I put ^\S+\s* in this field I got as result "Actors: "

Comment: ya, replace the matched string with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you be only getting the data after "Actors: " all time?

Try this:
" \w+.+\w" or ": (\w+.+\w)"

Note: Remove the quotes.